# Repeat subreport over multiple pages

Tags: crystal-reports, report

I have a main report that has 3 sub reports in the details.  I need the two sub reports, shown by the arrows on the right titled, exposure data and defect code, to repeat if the details of the sub report, shown on the left, extends more than 1 page.
[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Place the two subreports on the group-header instead, then set the following settings.

- Activate `Underlay Following Section` on the group-header-section you placed the subreports
- Activate `Repeat group header on each page` in group-expert (`change group` -> `options tab`).

If there isn't a group already, create one that doesn't change the structure of the report.

For example, if the data shown in the picture belongs to a specific location, then group by location-(id).

Comment: YOU ARE THE MAN!